# efficient organziation of geographic state/region/content for entries

Tags: taxonomy-terms

This is kind of a general question, but maybe someone has an idea.

I have a database that will have 300,000+ entries. Each one of these entries will have multiple entries for 'location' - not specific locations, and not gps coordinants. It's regions, across the world. And there can be numerous locations for each entry.

The way I have it in attempt one, is to create a taxonomy of locations to choose from, with hierarchy of Contenent --> subcontinent --> country --> state/dept/province. Within the entry form for each item, there's a select list that pulls each region from the taxonomy, and drill down to smaller regions in a subsequent dropdown, with each selection.

I didn't think this would become such a load on the system, but it certainly has using such a large set of taxonomy terms in one vocabulary. Maybe someone has come up with a lighter way of doing this?

Comment: This question sounds like it falls under "unclear what you're asking." Anyway, 2 suggestions: either change your content model to not include such a massive taxonomy or optimize queries/caching so it could handle such a dataset.

Comment: Yeah... I kinda wanted to delete the question, but that option isn't available to me